# Having trouble repainting circles on button click

Tags: java, events, swing, awt

I am having trouble making my window repaint when clicking a button. What's supposed to happen when I click the button is more circles should be drawn on the frame (it should technically be the number of circles drawn last time * 2). For some reason, it's not working and I can't really figure out why it wont repaint. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Roaches {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create the frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        //Set the frame's size
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Roaches!");
        //Create the button
        JButton button = new JButton("Multiply Roaches!");
        button.addActionListener(new Roach());
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        //Add the button to the panel
        buttonPanel.add(button);
        //Add the panel to the frame
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //Add the roach panel to the frame
        frame.add(new Roach());
        //Make frame visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class Roach extends JComponent implements ActionListener {
    //Keep track of how many roaches to draw
    private int roachCount = 1;
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D)g;
        for(int i = 0; i < roachCount; i++) {
            int x = 5 * i;
            int y = 5 * 1;
            gr.drawOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        }
        System.out.println("REPAINT"); //For testing
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        roachCount = roachCount * 2;
        repaint();
        System.out.println("CLICK!!!!"); //For testing
    }
}
```

I don't know if I have the concept of events or repainting wrong, so any help/pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to create a `new Roach()` the second time. Just create one roach and keep a reference to it and use the reference everywhere.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create the frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        //Set the frame's size
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Roaches!");
        //Create the button
        JButton button = new JButton("Multiply Roaches!");

        Roach roach = new Roach();

        button.addActionListener(roach);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        //Add the button to the panel
        buttonPanel.add(button);
        //Add the panel to the frame
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //Add the roach panel to the frame
        frame.add(roach);
        //Make frame visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked perfectly. I can't believe that was the issue. It was starting to drive me crazy :) Does everything else look okay to you? It's working now, but I am still relatively new to Java and want to make sure I'm following "good practices" or keeping in line with the way things are supposed to be done...

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're creating two instances of Roach.  One that you add as an action listener to your JButton and the other that you add to the frame to draw.  Because they are different instances, the Roach that is drawn never receives an action and thus always has a count of 1.

This is actually a good example of why I dislike the practice of implementing listener interfaces on gui objects.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I had totally overlooked that but I don't think I would have caught that. I was getting a little confused about how you're supposed to pass everything in to certain objects/methods the right way. Thanks again for your answer!